# Unable to sendall via socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

My problem is that when I try to send some data over using sendall(data),  get an error

```
db.connected_users[indexx].sendall(usr+' - '+data)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

This even happens when I .encode() the data to send. db.connected_users is a dictionary with a keypair as of 'username':conn where conn is the result of conn,addr = s.accept()

This is very strange, and I don't understand how to fix it. If any further details are required, please ask in the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to convert a `bytes` object to `str` you need to **decode** it not encode it, like this:

```
bytes_data = b"some data"
string_data = bytes_data.decode('utf-8')
```